# Finding the right function in Excel to calculate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data like this:

```
       A:        B:   C:
1:   4-jan-16   117   85
2:  11-jan-16    58   11
3:  18-jan-16   101   98
...
```

and so on up to `2-jan-17`.

I need to calculate the difference between `b1-c1`, `b2-c1` for each month (`c1=85=Jan`, `c2=111=Feb`, `c3=98=March`).

Then I need to take the difference of every week and ^2

I have no clue on how to go about it, I have looked up many function just not sure which would do the trick. Please feel free to ask for additional details...

## UPDATE

outcome should be (add a column `D`)

```
       A:        B:   C:      D:
1:   4-jan-16   117   85      =b1-c1
2:  11-jan-16    58   11      =b2-c1
3:  18-jan-16   101   98      =b3-c1 
4:  25-jan-16   110   10      =b4-c1
5:   1-Feb-16   52            =b5-c2
```

For the column `B`, I used the following (have 2 sheets one called `BE`, the other `sheet1`)

```
=AVERAGEIFS('BE'!$H$157:$H$208,'BE'!$B$157:$B$208,">="&A7,'BE'!$B$157:$B$208,"<="&EOMONTH(Sheet1!A7,0))
```

Was wondering if I could use something like that to calculate the difference for every week in column `D`

Comment: I took your sample data and displayed them as a table. I don't understand the labels in column `A` when you are saying that 1st row is January, 2nd row February, ... Also I have no idea what you mean by `^2` - please clarify and add an **example of desired output**.

Comment: Column a = Dates, Column b = qty used for the week so for 4-jan-16 I used 117, the column c1 is the mean (average) of the month for Jan, c2 is the mean (average) for the month of Feb and c3 is the mean of March., What I'm trying to do is find the difference of each week of january - using the appropriate cell in column c,so for Jan you would do b1-c1, then b2-c1, then b3-c1 since c1 is the average for the month of January. I must find the difference for every week base on the month

Comment: @Vinocamp edit your question, and insert another table at the bottom showing expected results.

Answer (score 1):

In D1 use the following and copy down.

```
=B1-INDEX($C$1:$C$4,MONTH(A1))
```

C1:C4 is the range for you month results This method will only word for the 1 year and needs your data start in January as that is month 1.  The formula above also assumes your data start in row 1.  If you Data does not start in row 1 then you would want to modify the formula as follows:

```
=B5-INDEX($C$5:$C$16,MONTH(A5)+row(A5)-(row($A$5)-1))
'This example assumes your data stated in row 5 and you had 12 month of monthly data in column C.
```